# Should data tables be made in pen or pencil?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, teaching-lab

For a chemistry lab, I have to make a data table. Should data tables be written in pen or pencil? What is done in the real world of Chemists and why is it done in such a way?

Comment: For a "professional" lab book the pages should be written in ink and witnessed.

Comment: We usually use computers nowadays. For your personal notes anything should be fine. When you have to write a report, you should consult your teacher or adviser about the official guidelines.

Comment: Just don't use erasable pens (like Pilot FriXion). The ink degrades very fast upon heating and also over time. I knew a person who lost some lab notes because hot air from the laptop was blowing towards the pile of the notes, and some of them were made with erasable pen.

Comment: Also, if you like to do note taking at the bench where the solvents and solutions are stored, I'd recommend using pencil. Inks are not very spill-resistant.

Comment: @andselisk you can make it reappear by cooling it down, e.g. in the freezer. Liquid nitrogen works too ;-)

Comment: @DSVA I'll pass this wisdom – looking forward to a Dewar with a pack of tied lab notebooks casually "chilling" at the desk  :D

Comment: @andselisk What a chill way to deal with invisible ink!

Comment: @andselisk funny picture you painted there. Liquid nitrogen is actually too cold (has to be a kinetic thing) but during warming up it reaches the right temperature  for the ink to reappear. It can also be repeated for at least some cycles in my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps is more a curiosity than an answer. Normally and for patenting purposes a lab journal should be written in permanent ink and witnessed, as said in other answers. Not sure about the validity of digital media , although they are crucial too in case of disputes or investigation. However, in my lab (master thesis), journals were written in pencil as the information is not lost in case of spilling. Water and solvents were always around the lab book, at least searching for eluents etc if not to run the reactions. We students had a lot of space in the labs but not a real office desk.

Comment: Frankly, a lab journal should be ‘clean’ and thus never on the bench, in the hood, or anywhere else where there is even the risk of spillage. Furthermore, you should not spill as each solvent spillage can be detrimental to your health and clean working is suggested.

Comment: @Jan. Thanks.chemist since the 80s here. Not to mention who preceded me. Ps we were lucky to have new labs and lot of spaces for reacting. Never saw so tidy labs anymore anywhere. Have you ever been in an organic chemistry lab? Have you ever copied your tlc for real or compared the tlc already in a journal to your actual one while running a column? But you are right. What shall I say. Ps2 from a time in which latex gloves and safety goggles were often left alone. And recrystallisation was done without mounting a condenser atop the erlenmayer :)

Comment: You obviously didn’t check my profile because I have spent my entire working days in organic labs since 2012 when I did my master’s. But no hard feelings ;) I actually always try to keep my bench and hood clean (meaning also that chaos from the neighbours stops right at a line; if needed, I push stuff back). I copy my TLCs in a transparent foil on the copying machine (very likely not an option in the 80’s). In my previous lab, I walked back to my desk if I wanted to compare, now I have a practically desk-like space (which I keep free of chemicals) right behind my hood.

Comment: But usually, I would run the column, record the TLCs and then take the copies to compare with the ones already in my journal. Safe and clean working is possible, you just have to want it and be prepared to live with the consequences ;)

Comment: No polemic here too. It was more or less a witnessed story. I keep my organic notes in pencil still nowadays. But I have two journals has my work is synthesis than implementation. In case I feel I hand copy the recipe to the witnessed " physics" applied one. Didn't see your profile but I knew you are of the safety goggles generation. We did improved ;)

Answer (score 3):

In the real world, chemists have a lab journal to document what they did; Good Scientific Practice guidelines state that results should be written there immediately, readably, non-removably, directly and a few other adverbs. ‘Great’ scientific practice or patent-safe documentation would require a witness.

In universities, I have heard of a trend of more and more lab journals being replaced by computer files. In the labs I have worked in, this was not the case and the paper lab journal remained the way to go. Apparantly, if you want to document something in a patent-safe manner, a paper book is mandatory.

Since the entries into a lab journal must not be removable, the only option you have is ink; usually, ball-point pens (biros) are used.

---

However, the wording of your question (‘chemistry lab’ and ‘data table’) makes me think you could still be a student. In that case, the only advice you should take is that of your teacher/advisor/…

Comment: My labs have used electronic lab notebooks for about the last 8 years. TLCs are recorded as .jpgs

Comment: @Waylander Especially interesting considering your profile says you work for pharma, which is a patent-sensitive industry! All I can do is repeat what I was told at my previous position (a Helmholtz centre), namely that only hand-written, dated documents signed by oneself and a witness would be accepted in patent disputes. (But the guy who told me was not in the patent department of the centre, so ~ xD)

Comment: It took a lot of arguing with the patent attorneys but it was implemented. AFAIK most big pharma now uses ELNs

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to draw the table itself in pencil and write the data inside it in pen.
Of course, it's best to ask your teacher about the guidelines, just to be sure.